# How can i trigger exception in laravel PHPunit Tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I am facing an issue while trying to test the exception handling in a Laravel controller that involves database interactions. Specifically, I want to test the catch block of an exception in the store method of my controller. The store method looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request, Pipeline $pipeline)
{
    try {
        $request->validate([
            "name" => ["required", "max:512"],
            "stage" => ["required", "in:".Stage::toCSV()],
        ]);

        // Database interaction here (e.g., MyModel::create())

        return response()->json(["message" => trans("round.created")], 201);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Exception in MyController@store: ' . $e->getMessage());
        Log::error('Stack trace: ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
        return redirect()->back()->banner(trans('error'));
    }
}
```

this is what i tried so far

```
$this->mock(\App\Models\MyModel::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('create')
                ->once()
                ->andThrow(new \Exception('Simulated exception'));
        });
```

```
$this->mock(\Exception::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('getMessage')->andReturn('Mocked exception message');
        });
```

Any suggestions or guidance on how to correctly mock the database interaction to simulate an exception and test the catch block would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The best way to test the catch block of an exception in your Laravel controller's store method, is to mock  the database interaction so that it throws an exception. for this you need to mock the MyModel class to throw an exception during the create method call
for this I would suggest to inject model as a dependency to controller so you can create an mock model any pass it and test its functionality

```
use App\Models\MyModel;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, MyModel $model, Pipeline $pipeline)
    {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                "name" => ["required", "max:512"],
                "stage" => ["required", "in:".Stage::toCSV()],
            ]);

            // Use the injected model for database interaction
            $model->create([
                // Your data here
            ]);

            return response()->json(["message" => trans("round.created")], 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Exception in MyController@store: ' . $e->getMessage());
            Log::error('Stack trace: ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
            return redirect()->back()->banner(trans('error'));
        }
    }
}
```

or You could go for a service based approach.
In both cases you can mock the Model/Service and then inject the mocked dependency to you controller and test it

to create mock you can use mock builders or mockery or

an anonymous class

```
$modelMock = new class extends MyModel {
            public static function create(array $attributes = [])
            {
                // Throw an exception when create is called
                throw new \Exception('Simulated exception');
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks Arun for your quick response, but can you please show an example how can i achieve this, i don't want to add any test related logic in the controller.

Comment: @Yashgupta Mocking model using an anonymous class and DI is already in answer, do you want know how to test these?

Comment: yes , what should i write in test to mock the lifecycle of the model. can please provide an example for the same , thanks for helping me